# Is there a limit of 2^23-1 files in windows due to driver limitations?

Tags: windows, ntfs

In another question a user mentions that many drivers in Windows impose a limit of 2^23-1 files for ntfs.

[Max files per directory on NTFS vol vs FAT32](https://superuser.com/questions/446282/max-files-per-directory-on-ntfs-vol-vs-fat32)

Is this correct?  I can't find any other references to this, however I am empirically running into corruption issues with around 10 million files.

---

EDIT: Fyi- my files are in reasonably sized subdirectories (none with more than a few thousand files).  The problem arises somewhat consistently when I unrar an archive of millions of smallish files.

Comment: "Maximum number of files in a single folder: 4,294,967,295", that is over 4 billion.

Comment: [Your issue may be file fragmentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories) and not the amount of files

Comment: [Number of files in a folder is also a "theoretical" limit.](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc938937)

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, why would any one directory need to have 10 million or more files instead of some sensible (or nonsense) sub-directory structure?

Comment: My files are in subdirectoires