# Physical disk space consumed by a file and its name

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, fat32

While transferring lots of files from a Linux Redhat workstation to a `FAT32` formatted external hard disk (`WD 2 TB` formatted by Mac disk utility), I ran into the error that there was not enough space left on my disk. But I checked there was still `~700 GB` of disk space left, so I am guessing I ran out of disk space because of long file names (not sure ?) ? How to check for that ?

My external HDD details are

```
/dev/sdc1 on /media/GUDDULINUX3 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=988,gid=2000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,s
```

Currently there are around `~545` directories with anything between `~7000` to `~11000` files in each directory. Each file is a binary file of size (checked with du -sh), `~32K` or `96K` (roughly half each) and the name is like `XC6_9k.131_132.12.2012.210.s3` (`29` characters long). The file size looks OK because they are supposed to be binary files with `8000` or `24000` floating points.

Is it possible something else is wrong ? Unfortunately, I cannot check the exact disk space consumed by the directories, trying `du -sh` takes forever.

**Edit 1**-
I used Mac Disk Utility to verify the external hard disk and it says -
`11361590 files, 1076797472 KiB free (33649921 clusters)`

**Edit 2**-

Following Angelo's suggestions, I tried `df -h` and `df -i` on the external hard disk attached to my laptop (mac). It looks like I have run out of free inodes in `/Volumes/GUDDULINUX3`. Any suggestions on what to do - will I gain inodes if I `tar` the small files in one `tar` file for each directory ? Should I move to an `NTFS` formatted disk ?

```
avinash$ df -h
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                       233Gi  216Gi   17Gi    93% 56587186 4482254   93%   /
devfs                              187Ki  187Ki    0Bi   100%      646       0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                           0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0       0  100%   /net
map auto_home                        0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0       0  100%   /home
/dev/disk1s1                       1.8Ti  836Gi  1.0Ti    45%        0       0  100%   /Volumes/GUDDULINUX3

avinash$ df -i
Filesystem                        512-blocks       Used  Available Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                       488555536  452185504   35858032    93% 56587186 4482254   93%   /
devfs                                    373        373          0   100%      646       0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                                 0          0          0   100%        0       0  100%   /net
map auto_home                              0          0          0   100%        0       0  100%   /home
localhost:/rGEmV8JCfpffeQBEQFAlLe  488555536  488555536          0   100%        0       0  100%   /Volumes/MobileBackups
/dev/disk1s1                      3906009792 1752414720 2153595072    45%        0       0  100%   /Volumes/GUDDULINUX3
```

These are results with the disk attached to my Linux workstation, it doesn't show the inode information.

```
seismo82% df -h /media/GUDDULINUX3/ 
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sdc1 1.9T 836G 1.1T 45% /media/GUDDULINUX3 

seismo82% df -i /media/GUDDULINUX3/
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1           0     0     0     - /media/GUDDULINUX3
```

**Edit 3**-

It seems like `inode` thing doesn't work with `FAT32`. I think the problem is that there is a lower limit in `FAT32` on how much files could be there in a directory, lower than `~65k` depending on the filename. First, I tarred a lot of per-existing files in the ext HDD, that should have freed up a lot of `inodes` (or `FAT32` equivalent). But still moving the big directory (it has `~23k` files) showed "no space left on device" error. Then, instead of moving individual files, I made a tar of the directory and moving it was possible to external disk !!! Trying to untar it in the ext disk gave me the error again. So, I think I ran into a limit on number of files in the directory. See **w3dk**'s comment on this 
[Max files per directory](https://superuser.com/questions/446282/max-files-per-directory-on-ntfs-vol-vs-fat32)

I checked the directories that had reported error on moving. The limit seems `16383` files for filenames with `29` characters and `21843` files for filenames with `20` characters. Theoretically, the limit is `~65k` files for files with names in `8.3` format. Thanks to everyone who helped me diagnose the issue. For now, I will just tar up whatever I have.

Comment: You should post the command you're running and the error you are receiving.  Max filename length is 255 characters.

Comment: sorry i dont remember the exact wording of the error but it was like "no space left on device". the command was `mv dir1/* /media/GUDDULINUX3/WK/dir1/*`, and then do this for multiple directories

Comment: And you didn't run out of space or inodes (df -h and df -i) ?

Comment: I tried df -sh, it was taking too much time, so I tried running Mac Disk Utility, it says `11361590 files, 1076797472 KiB free (33649921 clusters)`, I will try df -i, thanks

Comment: df should be instant

Comment: sorry i confused df with du, i will check again

Comment: Please see my edits with results of `df -h` and `df -i` commands, i didn't get anything from `df -i` command :'(

Comment: You might get a clue if you can see which file it's failing on.  Try to use mv -v.  Unfortunately, I can't think of anything at the moment that's obvious.

Comment: please see my revised Edit 2. I think I have run out of free inodes, should I just tar the small files ?

Comment: FAT doesn't really have "inodes" in the ext2/ext3 sense, but the total number of files is limited, and the "inodes" value is likely reporting that. So yes, taring the small files (or just all files in a directory) will get around this.

Comment: @dirkt  Yes--sorry for leading people astray.  I thought maybe it would translate inodes into available table-slots or some other similar accounting method for FAT.

Comment: @Guddu I don't think you can conclude from that output that you have run into a limit for number of files.  I'm pretty sure that OSX is just reporting 100% usage because it sees 0 available inodes and 0 inodes used.  I'm still uncertain where the problem is.  I use Mac/Windows/Linux also, so I understand how difficult it is to select a satisfactory filesystem for all 3.  I don't remember which I felt was better:  NTFS support on Mac or exFAT support on Linux.  I think I ended up just using NTFS and on OSX:  VirtualBox with Linux to mount and write to it because it was infrequent.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the partition size limits, file size limits, and directory size limits of the FAT32 file system (all of which it sounds like you are aware of), there is also a maximum limit of 268,435,437 total files on a FAT32 volume, regardless of directory.

Doing quick math, 545 directories with 7000 files in each is almost 4 *million* files -- far in excess of what FAT32 can handle.

Comment: sorry, i feel like i am missing something, 4 million is still less than 268 million ?

Comment: No, you are not missing anything. When I read your question I just *knew* you had to be running into some FS limit, so I googled those limits, saw 268 thousand, and decided that was it. Of course you are right... That's 268 million, not thousand, so my answer is wrong. I feel a bit embarrassed, but I got two upvotes for it! At least two other people made the same mistake I just did and that makes me feel less stupid. Hahaha!